# Python finding difference between two time stamps in minutes

Tags: python, timestamp, difference, minute

How i can find the difference between two time stamps in minutes . 
for example:-

```
timestamp1=2016-04-06 21:26:27
timestamp2=2016-04-07 09:06:02
difference = timestamp2-timestamp1
= 700 minutes (approx)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
tstamp1 = datetime.strptime('2016-04-06 21:26:27', fmt)
tstamp2 = datetime.strptime('2016-04-07 09:06:02', fmt)

if tstamp1 > tstamp2:
    td = tstamp1 - tstamp2
else:
    td = tstamp2 - tstamp1
td_mins = int(round(td.total_seconds() / 60))

print('The difference is approx. %s minutes' % td_mins)
```

Output is:

```
The difference is approx. 700 minutes
```

Comment: `td = tstamp1 - tstamp2 if tstamp1 > tstamp2 else tstamp2 - tstamp1` for a one-liner

Comment: `td_mins = int(round(abs((tstamp1 - tstamp2).total_seconds()) / 60))` if you just want to skip the if statements entirely