# Duration between two timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with different timestamp for each user, and I want to calculate the duration.
I used this code to import my CSV files:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\...\Desktop' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0,encoding='ISO-8859-1')
    li.append(df)

df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

df.head()

```
  ID     timestamp
1828765  31-05-2021 22:27:03    
1828765  31-05-2021 22:27:12    
1828765  31-05-2021 22:27:13    
1828765  31-05-2021 22:27:34
2056557  21-07-2021 10:27:12
2056557  21-07-2021 10:27:20
2056557  21-07-2021 10:27:22
```

And I want to get something like that

```
   ID    timestamp             duration(s)
1828765  31-05-2021 22:27:03    NAN
1828765  31-05-2021 22:27:12    9
1828765  31-05-2021 22:27:13    1
1828765  31-05-2021 22:27:34    21
2056557  21-07-2021 10:27:12    NAN
2056557  21-07-2021 10:27:20    8
2056557  21-07-2021 10:27:22    2
```

I've used this code, but doesn't work for me

```
import datetime
df['timestamp'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S") 
df['time_diff'] = 0
for i in range(df.shape[0] - 1):
    df['time_diff'][i+1] = (datetime.datetime.min +  (df['timestamp'][i+1] - df['timestamp'][i])).time()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python finding difference between two time stamps in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481189/python-finding-difference-between-two-time-stamps-in-minutes)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @HenryEcker I just read a csv file in jupyter and what you can see in the description is a few lines from the dataframe..

Comment: No worries, just keep in mind for the future; these tags would be appropriate if your issue was *related* to Jupyter (notebook).

Comment: @Hermoine this is a much improved question. I've retracted my downvote and also voted to reopen this question. I appreciate your willingness to provide more information and get it into the type of format we're looking for here.

Comment: I've used df['time_diff'][i+1] = df['timestamp'][i+1] - df['timestamp'][i] and it works :D Problem Resolved

Comment: The question will be eventually reopened, in which case it is highly advisable that you post this as an answer and accept it (after 48 hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operations which occur over groups of values are [GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html) operations in `pandas`.

`pandas` supports mathematical operations over timestamps natively. For this reason, subtraction will give the correct duration between any two timestamps.

We've already successfully converted out `timestamp` column to `datetime64[ns]`

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Now we can take the difference between rows within groups with [`Groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html)

```py
df['duration'] = df.groupby('ID')['timestamp'].diff()
```

`df`

```
        ID           timestamp        duration
0  1828765 2021-05-31 22:27:03             NaT
1  1828765 2021-05-31 22:27:12 0 days 00:00:09
2  1828765 2021-05-31 22:27:13 0 days 00:00:01
3  1828765 2021-05-31 22:27:34 0 days 00:00:21
4  2056557 2021-07-21 10:27:12             NaT
5  2056557 2021-07-21 10:27:20 0 days 00:00:08
6  2056557 2021-07-21 10:27:22 0 days 00:00:02
```

If we want to get the duration in seconds we can extract the total number of seconds using [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html#pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds):

```py
df['duration (s)'] = df.groupby('ID')['timestamp'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
```

`df`:

```
        ID           timestamp  duration (s)
0  1828765 2021-05-31 22:27:03           NaN
1  1828765 2021-05-31 22:27:12           9.0
2  1828765 2021-05-31 22:27:13           1.0
3  1828765 2021-05-31 22:27:34          21.0
4  2056557 2021-07-21 10:27:12           NaN
5  2056557 2021-07-21 10:27:20           8.0
6  2056557 2021-07-21 10:27:22           2.0
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1828765, 1828765, 1828765, 1828765, 2056557, 2056557, 2056557],
    'timestamp': ['31-05-2021 22:27:03', '31-05-2021 22:27:12',
                  '31-05-2021 22:27:13', '31-05-2021 22:27:34',
                  '21-07-2021 10:27:12', '21-07-2021 10:27:20',
                  '21-07-2021 10:27:22']
})

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
df['duration (s)'] = df.groupby('ID')['timestamp'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
print(df)
```