# "Value 0:00:00.416559 has unexpected type <class 'datetime.timedelta'>" when diff of two timestamps as value in jsonPayload gcloud logger.log_struct()

Tags: dictionary, google-cloud-platform, types, google-cloud-logging

Code:

```py
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
sleep(1)
diff = datetime.now() - start
```

When saving the `diff` variable as a value of a dictionary "my_dict" that will then be written to a jsonPayload output by the google cloud logging module with its function `log_struct(my_dict)`, I get:

```
Value 0:00:00.416559 has unexpected type <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

How to get the format as seconds instead to get rid of the datatype error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
diff = (datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
```

Taken from [Python finding difference between two time stamps in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481189/python-finding-difference-between-two-time-stamps-in-minutes).